# Passing parameters to a function in knockoutjs viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js

I have anchor tag like this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success order-btn" data-bind="attr:{'data-tiername':$data.tierName, 'data-identifier' : $parent.identifier}, click: $root.setPath.bind($data,$data.tierName, $parent.identifier)">Send values</a>
```

In the viewmodel

```
var appViewModel = {
    setPath: function (data, tier, identifier) {
        alert(data);
        alert(tier);
        alert(identifier);
    },
...........
...........
}
```

The result is some knockoutjs core code being displayed in alert message (possibly definitions of observable(),dependentObservable() functions and [Object object] which is empty when alerted with JSON.stringify)

why does this work?

```
data-bind="attr:{'data-tiername':$data.tierName, 'data-identifier' : $parent.identifier}
```

but not this:

```
click: $root.setPath.bind($data,$data.tierName, $parent.identifier)
```

note that tierName is an observable(), identifier is computed()

Where can I find more about bind() ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `tierName` and `identifier` are observables, you need to call them to access to their values:

```
click: $root.setPath.bind($data, $data.tierName(), $parent.identifier())
```

Also, first argument in `bind()` will be bound to `this` in `setPath`, so I guess you need something like this:

```
click: $root.setPath.bind(/*will be bound to this*/ $root, $data, 
                      $data.tierName(), $parent.identifier())
```

Finally, if `$data` itself is an observable (which is not clear if it is from you code), then you need to call it as well:

```
click: $root.setPath.bind($root, $data(), $data().tierName(), $parent.identifier())
```

Also remember *bind* has been introduced in ECMAScript 5, so it may not be present in all browsers. So I would probably do something like this instead:

```
click: function(){$root.setPath($data, $data.tierName(), $parent.identifier());}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is additional info on *bind*.

Comment: i wanted to do `alert(tier);
        alert(identifier);` in my viewmodel function, i didnt really want the context(this). So my function became `setPath(tier,identifier)` Thanks for helping out

Comment: KO does add an implementation of `bind` if it is not available, so if you are referencing KO, then you are safe to use `bind`.

Answer (score 6):

The first parameter to `bind` is the target (what you want `this` to be) when your function is executed.  So, if you want `data` to be the first argument, then it needs to be the second argument.

Inside your function, if you are dealing with observables or computed observables, then you need to unwrap them to see their value.  You would do this either by calling it as a function `alert(data());` or by calling `alert(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data));` (which is generally used when you don't know at design type if what you are going to be dealing with is an observable or a non-observable.

The reason that `attr` and other bindings work when you pass an observable/computed observable is that they all call `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` for you for convenience (so you don't have to add `()` when passing observables unless you are writing an expression `!$data()`.

Here is some reference on bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind