# Why is this knockout function being executed?

Tags: knockout.js

In my view:

```
<!-- ko if: !isEditingAboutMe() -->
<p data-bind="text: aboutMe()">@Model.AboutMe</p>
@if (Model.CurrentUserCanEdit)
{
    <a data-bind="click: editAboutMe">edit</a>
}
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: isEditingAboutMe() -->
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AboutMe, new { data_bind = "value: aboutMe" })
<a data-bind="click: saveAboutMe(userId)">save</a>
<a data-bind="click: cancelAboutMe">cancel</a>
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new ProfileVm(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))));
var userId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(User.Identity.Name));
</script>
```

My viewModel:

```
function ProfileVm(model) {
var self = this;

self.aboutMe = ko.observable(model.AboutMe);

self.saveAboutMe = function (username) {
    dataservice().updateAboutMe(username, self.aboutMe());
    self.isEditingAboutMe(false);
};

self.cancelAboutMe = function() {
    self.isEditingAboutMe(false);
};

self.isEditingAboutMe = ko.observable(false);
self.editAboutMe = function() {
    self.isEditingAboutMe(true);
};
}
```

When I click "edit", the DOM changes as I'd expect, but saveAboutMe is executed.  It should only be executed if I click 'save', hence the click: binding.  What's going on?

Comment: You're executing the function when you open and close the parenthesis "saveAboutMe(userId)", you just need to set the name of the function "saveAboutMe" on the click binding.

Comment: @rob.alarcon but I need to pass userId which isn't bound to the viewModel... or am I missing something?

Comment: That's specific to your code, but as I see, your "userId" variable is global, so you will have access to the variable in your "saveAboutMe" function, you don't need to pass in that. Try this: 1- Remove the "(userId)" from your function call, and in the function definition "saveAboutMe" try to print the "userId" to see if you have access (some self.saveAboutMe = function (username) { alert(userId);console.log(userId);}

Comment: @rob.alarcon you're saying it's impossible to explicitly define parameters in click bindings?  I could swear I've done that before...

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, you can. You're missing the bind, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418224/passing-parameters-to-a-function-in-knockoutjs-viewmodel

Comment: @rob.alarcon Interesting... it works if I pull the parentheses like you suggested.  It feels a bit dirty having it as a global variable though... not to drive off-topic, but what would you do in this scenario?  Feel free to make your above suggestion an answer too and I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing the function when you open and close the parenthesis "saveAboutMe(userId)", you just need to set the name of the function "saveAboutMe" on the click binding.

1. Remove the "(userId)" from your function call
2. In the function definition "saveAboutMe"
3. You can use "userId" in your function because its global.

What you can do to make this a little bit cleaner if you wish is to pass in the global variable to your "save" function.

```
userId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(User.Identity.Name));
```

And in your click binding:

```
<a data-bind="click: function(){saveAboutMe(userId);}">save</a>
```

What you had been doing here is to define an anonymous function that will call "saveAboutMe" when the user click the "save" anchor. The difference between this and what you are doing is that here, the anonymous function is just defined, not executed.

another cleaner thing is to add the userId to your ko ViewModel and just make a reference to it in the function:

```
self.saveAboutMe = function (username) {
    console.log(self.userId); // this should work if you add your userId to your view model.
    dataservice().updateAboutMe(username, self.aboutMe());
    self.isEditingAboutMe(false);
};
```