# Knockout return function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an `a` tag like this:

```
 <a class="pull-right" data-bind="click: $root.CheckTimeOut, 
    attr:{'href': webcontext + 'Reporting/CSVReport?id=' + id() +
    '&session=' + $root.user.session() }">Table</a>
```

when the user click to this `a` tag then it will jump to the `CheckTimeOut` function to check if the Timer is already over or not:

```
self.CheckTimeOut = function(){

    $.getJSON(package + "Backend?session="+ self.user.session(), function(result) {
        if(result.result){
            console.log('Timer is not over');
            return true;
        }else{
            msg.error.timeOut();
            return false;
        }
    })

}
```

What I should expect is if the backend return `result = true` then means the **timer is not over**, then the function `CheckTimeOut` **should return true**, so that the `'href': webcontext + 'Reporting/CSVReport?id=' + id() + '&session=' + $root.user.session()` will be executed. Otherwise if the backend return `result = false` then an message error will appear and no thing happen. But actually when the backend return `result = true`, the `CheckTimeOut` function **print only the console.log**, but **not return true** back. Can anyone help me why the `CheckTimeOut` function not return value back?

Comment: You can't return from within your `getJSON` callback and expect the return value to be forwarded to your `CheckTimeOut` function...

Comment: What @Cristy said. Instead you could execute the href reference inside the sucecss part of the getJSON instead of returning a boolean.

Comment: I tried to edit by return the value out of the JSON request, but sometime it works, sometime not because sometime the JSON request is so slowly and the request isn't finished but then it jump directly to the return function

Comment: but what make me confused here is the data-bind Click automatically execute, no matter I click to it or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CheckTimeOut` function doesn't return anything: it calls an asynchronous method, and exits. You can't pass the `return true` or `return false` from the *callback* that handles the result, since it would return the value to JQuery, which ignores the result.

You *could* change the getJSON to make a synchronous call but this is **not recommended** and being deprecated in JQuery since it results in a blocking call.

There are many possible ways around this, you could save the URL in your knockout model, and when the .getJSON call executes, if the callback returns the right true/false value, navigate using `window.location = newURL;`

Comment: it's a good idea, Quango. Follow your idea, what I have changed is : <a class="pull-right" data-bind="click: $root.CheckTimeOut(uuid())"> csv </a>,
then in my viewModel: self.CheckTimeOut = function(uid){$.getJSON(window.location....)}

Comment: but then I got new problem that everytime I load the page, it automatically goes to the JSON request, no matter I click the a tag or not. How can I prevent it

Comment: Sounds like you're calling the function: is the binding this?
`"click: $root.CheckTimeOut()`

Comment: yep, it the binding: data-bind="click: $root.CheckTimeOut(uuid())", I would like to send also the parameter uuid() to the CheckTimeOut function, so that I can use it to create the link to call it inside of my getJSON

Comment: OK.. when you use parentheses it calls the method immediately. You need this mehtod instead: `data-bind="click: $root.CheckTimeOut.bind($root, uuid);`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418224/passing-parameters-to-a-function-in-knockoutjs-viewmodel

Comment: Though a workable fix, I recommend against passing items like that in your view. Instead, make sure your scopes are correct in the ViewModel side, and build the URL using the uuid *there*.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer(s) already mention the *issue* you have: the `CheckTimeout` function returns (`undefined`) *immediately*, and the `getJSON` calls will *asynchronously* call the callback function at some later moment. This is by design, and you should embrace that.

Here's an alternative way to handle this with a computed observable that triggers view model updates based on the return value of your Ajax call:

```js
// Mock ajax calls:
var $ = {
  getJSON: function(txt, callback) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      callback({ result: (Math.random() < 0.5) }); // Returns random result for testing
    }, Math.random() * 1000 + 200); // Random latency between 200 and 1200 ms
  }
};

function User(data) {
  var self = this, _recentResponse = ko.observable(null);
  
  self.uuid = ko.observable('fake-uuid-'+data);
  self.id = ko.observable('fake-id-'+data);
  
  self.recentResponse = ko.computed({
    read: function() { return _recentResponse(); },
    write: function(val) {
      var resp = { txt: (new Date()).toISOString() + " " + val.toString(), val: val };
      _recentResponse(resp);
      self.responses.push(resp);
      if (!!val) {
        console.log('Timer is not over');
      } else {
        console.log("msg.error.timeOut()");
      }
    }
  });
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.users = ko.observableArray([new User('a1'), new User('a2')]);
    
  self.CheckTimeOut = function(user) {
    console.log(user);
    $.getJSON("url-for-uuid" + user.uuid(), function(result) {
      user.recentResponse(result.result);
    })
    return true;
  }
};

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

window.setInterval(function() { vm.CheckTimeOut(vm.users()[0]); } , 2500);
window.setInterval(function() { vm.CheckTimeOut(vm.users()[1]); } , 2500);
```

```css
.msg { background: red; }
.success { background: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Users:
<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
  <li>
    User <strong data-bind="text: uuid"></strong> - 
    <a href="#" class="pull-right" data-bind="click: $root.CheckTimeOut">CheckTimeOut Manually</a>
    Recent response:
    <!-- ko with: recentResponse -->
    <span data-bind="text: txt, css: { success: val }" class="msg"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution sequence is 1-2-3-4-5

```
self.CheckTimeOut = function(){
    // (1) Function begin executing
    // Here we call $.getJSON function. The $.getJSON is asynchronous
    $.getJSON(package + "Backend?session="+ self.user.session(), 
      // And pass new function as a parameter for $.getJSON function
      function(result) {
        // (4) After request has been completed
        // this operations are performed
        if(result.result){
            console.log('Timer is not over');
            // (5) And this is returned to the $.getJSON function
            return true;
        }else{
            msg.error.timeOut();
            // (5) And this is returned to the $.getJSON function also
            return false;
        }
     })

    // (2) $.getJSON sends request and immediately returns nothing and CheckTimeOut is continued
    // Since there are no "return" statement in the CheckTimeOut function
    // (3) it returns undefined, that you got as a result
   }
```